# A2DP from phone to Mac

Tags: bluetooth, audio

Is it possible to use your Mac as an A2DP receiver with your phone as the transmitter?  This way, I can get notifications from the phone while at my desk, without having to take out my headphones which are connected to my Mac?

Comment: That entirely depends on whether you can get the appropriate drivers and software for your PC.

Comment: what would you need as far as drivers and software go?  (i'm on a mac)

Comment: Software to make it act as an A2DP receiver, of course. So far this sounds more like a question about your Mac than a question about Android.